# The expectation of absolute value of the sum of n i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, absolute-value, expected-value

Let $\varphi_i$ be a Gaussian random variable such that
$$\varphi_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2), \quad i = 1,2,\ldots,n.$$
What's the expectation:
$$E\left(\left | \sum_{i=1}^n e^{j \varphi_i} \right |\right) $$
where $\left | \cdot \right |$ is the absolute value operation and $j = \sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: I don't know if there is a nice closed form for the absolute value but for the square of the absolute value the expectation is $\frac{n (n-1)}{\exp \left(\sigma ^2\right)}+n$.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation you are interested in is equivalent to

$$E\left[\sqrt{n+2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^n (\cos \varphi_j \cos \varphi_k+\sin\varphi_j \sin\varphi_k)}\right]$$

I don't believe there is a nice closed-form solution for that expectation.  So I think you'll need to perform simulations or numerically integrate to get solutions.

If you were interested in

$$E\left[n+2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^n (\cos \varphi_j \cos \varphi_k+\sin\varphi_j \sin\varphi_k)\right]$$

then there is a closed-form solution:

$$n+n(n-1)e^{-\sigma^2}$$

Comment: hi, since X is always positive, do we have $E[\sqrt{X}] = \sqrt{ E[X] }$? If it holds, the first expectation can have a closed-form solution, right?

Comment: @Vic No.  If that were the case, then by your argument you'd have $E[X^2]=E[X]^2$ which would imply that all variances are identically zero.

Comment: that’s right. BTW, Jim, it seems that there is closed form solution for $$E\left(\left | \sum_{i=1}^n e^{j \varphi_i} \right |^{2}\right). $$ 

I am curious whether there is always closed-form solution or formula of expansion for $$E\left(\left | \sum_{i=1}^n e^{j \varphi_i} \right |^{2k}\right),$$ where $k$ is some integer.

Comment: @Vic  You should ask that as a question.

Comment: Yes, that sounds a good idea. I have raised a question and considered a more general case. Jim, can you also have a look https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3910426/solving-the-expectation-e-left-left-sum-i-1n-x-i-ej-varphi-i-righ

Comment: Hi, @JimB I have one question on the result you gave, how is the imaginary term that comes from the $exp(j\varphi_{i})$ gone. I have derived a more general case below but cannot get rid of the imaginary term. Could you give me some hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$ \left| \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n} e^{j\theta_{n}} \right|^2 =  \left| \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n} e^{j\theta_{n}} \right)^2 \right| =  \left| \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n}^{2} + 2 \sum_{m=1}^{N} \sum_{n=m+1}^{N} z_{m} z_{n} e^{j (\theta_{m}+\theta_{n}) }  \right| 
=  \left| \sum_{n=1}^{N} z_{n}^{2} + 2 \sum_{m=1}^{N} \sum_{n=m+1}^{N} z_{m} z_{n} \cdot \left[ \cos( \theta_{m} ) \cos( \theta_{n} ) - \sin( \theta_{m} ) \sin( \theta_{n} ) + j \cos( \theta_{m}) \sin(\theta_{n} ) + j \sin( \theta_{m}) \cos(\theta_{n} )  \right]   \right| 
$$

Comment: Use the definition of absolute value:  $|z|=\sqrt{z\cdot \bar{z}}$.