# Solving the expectation $E\left[\left | \sum_{i=1}^N X_{i} e^{j \varphi_i} \right |^{2k}\right] $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X_i$ and $\varphi_i$ be some independent and indentical (i.i.d.) RVs with known distributions (assuming $\varphi_{i}$ is uniformly distributed between [$-a\pi$, $a\pi$] with $a$ being some constant). Can the following expectation be expressed in terms of the expectations related to the RVs $X_i$ and $\varphi_i$?
$$E\left[\left | \sum_{i=1}^N X_{i} e^{j \varphi_i} \right |^{2k}\right] $$
where $k$ is a positive integer.

For example, for the case of k = 1, we have $$E\left[\left | \sum_{i=1}^N X_{i} e^{j \varphi_i} \right |^{2}\right] = N E\left[X_i^2\right] + 2\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^N E\left[X_j X_k\right]  E\left[(\cos \varphi_j \cos \varphi_k+\sin\varphi_j \sin\varphi_k)\right] $$

But how about the cases for $k > 1$, are there any formulas or unified expressions for the expectation.

Comment: The a good bet would: find the distribution of the sum first. Some restriction on the $\phi$'s would simplify the process you started with too ...

Comment: @Math-fun yes, I think so, I have assumed that $\varphi$ is symmetric around 0, so I think the sine terms should be cancelled out statistically even without the absolute operation, is that what you mean?